# Probability distribution, expectation and variance

Tags: probability

Radius of a circle is approximately measured. Considering that its size is uniformly staggered on an interval $[a,b],(a,b>0)$, find the distribution of probabilities of the circle area, its expectation and variance.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $R$ be the radius of the circle. The description is a little unclear, but I assume it means that $R\sim\operatorname{unif}[a,b]$. If we let $A$ be the area of the random circle, then you are asked to find the variance and expectation of the random variable
$$A = \pi R^2.$$

Use your favorite method to find the distribution of $A$. People often like $F_A(a) = P(A\leq a) $.